# is there any way to reduce the time to export video using AVAssetExportSession in ios to export edited video without reducing quality

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

i have writen following code to export my video with an overlay layer but for one minute video it is taking a lot of time to export. How can i reduce the time to export the video in less time without reducing the quality.

i have tried this

```
func exportVideo(composition: AVMutableComposition, videoComposition: AVMutableVideoComposition, onComplete: @escaping (URL?) -> Void){
        guard let export = AVAssetExportSession(
            asset: composition,
            presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality)
        else {
            print("Cannot create export session.")
            onComplete(nil)
            return
        }
        
        let videoName = UUID().uuidString
        let exportURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
            .appendingPathComponent(videoName)
            .appendingPathExtension("mov")
        
        export.videoComposition = videoComposition
        export.outputFileType = .mov
        export.outputURL = exportURL
        
        export.exportAsynchronously {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch export.status {
                case .completed:
                    onComplete(exportURL)
                default:
                    print("Something went wrong during export.")
                    print(export.error ?? "unknown error")
                    onComplete(nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of video are you exporting, codec, resolution, etc.? How much is "a lot of time to export", on which computer model?